# Unable to connect IBOutlets to Storyboards

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, storyboard

I've recently started creating an iPhone interface for my iPad application using storyboards, I've changed the project to Universal instead of iPad and assigned the desired storyboard to its device in the project summary screen.
But when I try to connect any element using control+drag to a piece of code such as:

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *logo;
```

It just can't link it. The object IS the same type as the code says, same as the View is the same class inheritance. The iPad storyboard is still working well and can be enhanced, it's still linked to the project. The new iPhone storyboard is completely useless, why is that?

Comment: Have you set the correct File Owner?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This happens when the view controller in the storyboard for the scene you are working on is not set to the correct class.

Here's roughly how it should look:

[image]

Comment: I can't believe I forgot that! Thank you!