# UIWebView IBOutlet Connection issue

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uiviewcontroller, uiwebview

So I'm going to try to explain my issue as best I can.

I have 2 View Controllers on a Storyboard. One is the "main" VC and the second is a "EULA" VC.

The main view controller has a UIWebView which loads the primary UI and works fine. This controller uses code to perform a Modal segue to the EULA VC which is created in the interface builder. This also works fine.

Now here lies my problem. The EULA view controller also has a UIWebView on it but I can't seem to connect this view controller to any connection by means of CTRL + drag. The "main" UIWebView is connected to ViewController.h

This is how I create my connection with CTRL + drag:
[image: UIWebView Connection]

**My question is why am I able to connect the first UIWebView on the Main view controller but not the other UIWebView on the EULA view controller? What am I missing?**

Comment: Have you tried it on EULAViewController.h ?

Comment: I did not have a EULAViewController.h so I just created a new class "EULAViewController" which created the .h and .m files (implementation and such). I was still not able to connect it. I was under the impression ViewController.h works for all of the Views controllers?

Comment: have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/a/12569675/1462920 . this may help you!

Comment: Thanks! That's exactly what my problem is but as my comment states on another answer, I receive an error when attempting to connect it to my class "EULAViewController.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you set up the EULAViewController.h as the custom class for the ViewController in Interface builder? Select the UIViewContoller in Interface Builder and in the third tab make sure the class is correct. Here is a screenshot explaining what I am saying:

[image: CustomClass in IB]

Also make sure you have selected the correct file in the right pane, both red boxes should show the name of your custom UIViewController subclass:

[image: Right Pane]

Comment: Aha! Now I'm getting somewhere. I set the class to "EULAViewController" but when trying to create the outlet I get the error: Could not insert new outlet connection: Could not find any information for the class name EULAViewController

Comment: Use the name of the UIViewController subclass you created, "EULAViewController" was just a name I used to show you as an example, yours probably has a different name. The name should appear if you click on the little arrow pointing down at the right.

Comment: It's a coincidence but "EULAViewController" was exactly what I named it. I have found another issue on SO that has the same problem. It could very well be a bug in xcode.

Comment: This along with the additional steps in my answer solved the problem. I will give you the answer.

Answer (score 1):

I am think this is a bug in XCode or what. But this is very rare issue. I also got this issue sometime. So posting a solution which can make you little nervous to implement. But it works for me sometimes. You can try it . -

Just create a new UIViewController subclass in your project and name it something slightly different than the first. Then, copy/paste all code from old non-working UIViewController into the new UIViewController subclass (.h and .m) and change all relevant symbols according to the new UIViewController subclass name. After doing this I found everything worked as normal in terms of trying to control-drag wiring the buttons.

Happy coding. :)

Comment: Thanks NSS, I too believe this is a bug in XCode. I was not able to reproduce this problem in a new project so it must be somewhat rare. This is how I fixed the issue!

Answer (score 0):

Recreating the class files, renaming the view to something else then back to EULAViewController AND following these steps I was able to fix the issue.

1. Close the project you are working on with.
2. Delete the【DerivedData】folder of you project. (This folder may
   inside your project's folder, or inside
   ~/Library/Developer/XCode/DerivedData/(your project)/ ) or somewhere
   else that were setup by you.
3. restart you project.